# MSP430 interrupt issue with the MSPFET Emulator connected

Tags: microcontroller, interrupts, ti-ccstudio

[image]I'm using the emulator MSPFET Flash to program the MCU MSP430F5507. There is a peripheral interrupt subroutine that should receive an external interrupt every 1 second.
I have a problem that the interrupt doesn't work until I disconnect the emulator.
The interrupt is active low, and a pull-up resistor is connected to the pin.
If the emulator is disconnected, the interrupt signal is by default high and a low pulse is coming every 1 second and is watched on the scope.
But, once the emulator is connected the interrupt signal is low and doesn't go high even though the pin is pulled up in hardware.

Anyone have a suggestion for this issue??

Comment: Are your interrupt pin shared with the emulator connections?

Comment: No, The emulator pins are different and I'm using Spy-Bi-Wire interface with the emulator.

Comment: Which pin? How is it configured?

Comment: The emulator is connected to SBWTDIO, SBWTCK. And the interrupt peripheral is P2.0.